# Adding small scroll icon when a new row is been added to table view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview, scroll

Is there any way to show an icon in a table view when a new row is been added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track of which items are new externally to the table view.  Then for each of your table cells, check to see if the item is new.  If it is new, then set an image view on your custom table cell to be unhidden, and you should be good.

What you will need then:

- A model for each of your items you are displaying in your table, with an "isNewItem" property
- A custom cell view with you icon